# JQuery ajax send one form from many by click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am generating a form with phpClass:

```
   <`div id='admin_users' class=''><h1>Felhasználók</h1>
<table id='admin_user'><thead><tr><th>user_name</th><th>user_email</th><th>reg_time</th><th>activate time</th><th>admin</th></tr></thead>
<tr>
<form>
<td>123123</td>
<td>n**********ng@gmail.com</td>
<td>2014-01-01 23:13:58</td>
<td>2014-01-02 23:14:02</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' id='admin' class='admin' name='admin'  value='47' /></td><input type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='47' />
</form>
</tr>
<tr>
<form>
<td>Gabesz80</td>
<td>n***********ng@gmail.com</td>
<td>2013-12-30 12:46:26</td>
<td>2013-12-30 17:40:03</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' id='admin' class='admin' name='admin'  value='48' />
</td><input type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='48' />
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</div>`



echo "<tr><form>";
    echo "<td>".$q->user_name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$q->user_email."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$q->reg_time."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$q->activate_time."</td>";
    if($q->admin==1){
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' id='admin' class='admin'
 name='admin'  /></td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='admin' class='admin' name='admin' /></td>";
    }
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='".$q->user_id."' />";

    echo "</form></tr>";
```

The Jquery:

```
   $(':checkbox').click(function( event ) {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin_process.php",
            data: { admin : $(this).val(),
                user_id :  $('#user_id').val()  }
            }).done(function( msg ){
            alert("Az adatok: " + msg);     
        });
```

And the PHP:

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST)){
    echo   $_POST['user_id'] ;
    echo   $_POST['admin'] ;
}

?>
```

I try to select the next(), find(), $('#user_id') but I can't send to PHP the user_id of the line where I click. It always gives me back the id of the first line.
I have a user list, user name, email, admin (checkbox). 
When the user on the backend clicks on the checkbox, the AJAX should send a post to which updates the database admin cell from 1 to 0.
In my example have two users. When I send the data with the click it always send the data of the first line.

Comment: You said it is always sending the ID of the FIRST user.  But in your example I only see one user.  Are there multiple forms on the page and you are only showing us one?

Comment: form><td>123123</td><td>nemeth.gabor.ng@gmail.com</td><td>2014-01-01 23:13:58</td><td>2014-01-02 23:14:02</td><td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' id='admin' class='admin' name='admin'  value='47' /></td><input type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='47' /></form></tr><tr><form><td>Gabesz80</td><td>nemeth.gabor.ng@gmail.com</td><td>2013-12-30 12:46:26</td><td>2013-12-30 17:40:03</td><td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' id='admin' class='admin' name='admin'  value='48' /></td><input type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='48' /></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle that will get you what you need (the code is also below)... **http://jsfiddle.net/SYFeL/2/**

Couple things to note...

(1) I'm assuming you are only showing one user in your example but you really have many.  That is why your `$('#user_id').val()` selector is always giving you the first one, because the ID's are not unique.

(2) You do not need a hidden for the user_id, just add a the user_id to the value attribute of the checkbox

```
<form id="myForm">
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Gordon</td></tr>
        <tr><td>nobody@nobody.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>reg_time</td></tr>
        <tr><td>activate_time</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="101" /></td></tr> <!-- 101 is your user_id -->
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Gordon2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>nobody2@nobody.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>reg_time2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>activate_time2</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="202" /></td></tr> <!-- 202 is your user_id -->
    </table>
    ...more users, etc...
</form>

<script>
jQuery(':checkbox').click(function( event ) {

    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
        admin = '1';
    else
        admin = '0';

    var user_id = jQuery(this).val();

    alert('Make admin: '+admin);
    alert('What user am I making/not making an admin? '+user_id);
    alert('Now test unchecking the box...');
    return; //exiting out for the sake of this example, you will do the ajax below which submits 1,0 for make or unmake admin and it send the user_id.

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admin_process.php",
        data: { admin : admin, user_id : user_id }
    }).done(function( msg ){ alert("Az adatok: " + msg); });

});
</script>
```

Comment: tnx man! is(':checked') - is very usefull for me at now(). You give me a big boost.